# Ashtavinayaka locations names significance

Tags: temple, ganesha

[Ashtavinayaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashtavinayaka)

What is the significance of the eight Ashtavinayak locations names ?

Example : Morgaon, Pali, Rangangaon, Theur etc